# How to log out user and How to check user verify mail

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I got the following problem.
When user register he will be on a page, where I show a message like check your Email account. And when user check his account and confirm his mail he automatically get to homepage. So far so good. But when user press register button an get mail and reload the page he get also inside homepage without confirm his mail.
I trie this

```
Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {

    try {

      UserCredential result =await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password,
      );
      User user = result.user;

      if(user.emailVerified){
        return user.uid;
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
```

but not working.
here's my verify email page

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectandroidstudiodenya/seitenleiste/homepage.dart';

class VerifyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifyScreenState createState() => _VerifyScreenState();
}

class _VerifyScreenState extends State<VerifyScreen> {
  final auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    user= auth.currentUser;
    user.sendEmailVerification();
    timer= Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      checkEmailverifyed();

    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
timer.cancel();
super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        
      )
    );
  }

  Future<void> checkEmailverifyed() async{
    user=auth.currentUser;
    await user.reload();
    if(user.emailVerified){
      timer.cancel();
      Navigator.of(context).
      pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> Homepage()));
    }

  }
}
```

Maybe anyone can help.

And also when user press logout button  nothing happened. but when user restart the app he logged out.

here's my logout pressed method:

```
  onPressed: ()  {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginScreen.route, (route) => false);
```

Heres the error of the sign out:

```
D/FirebaseAuth(26776): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(26776): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
E/flutter (26776): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("SignIn", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
E/flutter (26776): Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
E/flutter (26776): this route.
E/flutter (26776): Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
E/flutter (26776):  1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
E/flutter (26776):  2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
E/flutter (26776):  3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
E/flutter (26776):  4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
E/flutter (26776): Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
E/flutter (26776): #0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1219:9)
E/flutter (26776): #1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1234:6)
E/flutter (26776): #2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4148:37)
E/flutter (26776): #3      NavigatorState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4391:34)
E/flutter (26776): #4      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2042:34)
E/flutter (26776): #5      _openSignOutDrawer.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/seitenleiste/seitenleiste.dart:188:90)
E/flutter (26776): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (26776): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (26776): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26776):
```

And the error of the sig in:

```
E/flutter (26776): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'emailVerified' was called on null.
E/flutter (26776): Receiver: null
E/flutter (26776): Tried calling: emailVerified
E/flutter (26776): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (26776): #1      AuthService.signIN (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/services/auth.dart:44:44)
E/flutter (26776): #2      _LoginScreenState._buildLoginBtn.<anonymous closure> (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/authenticate/signin.dart:170:48)
E/flutter (26776): #3      _LoginScreenState._buildLoginBtn.<anonymous closure> (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/authenticate/signin.dart:168:24)
E/flutter (26776): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:994:20)
E/flutter (26776): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (26776): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
E/flutter (26776): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter (26776): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
E/flutter (26776): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (26776): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
E/flutter (26776): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
E/flutter (26776): #12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:288:11)
E/flutter (26776): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter (26776): #14     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter (26776): #15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter (26776): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter (26776): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter (26776): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (26776): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (26776): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:186:10)
E/flutter (26776): #21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
E/flutter (26776): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
E/flutter (26776):
```

My sig in method looks like that:

```
Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {

 try {
      if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.emailVerified) {
        ( await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email.trim(), password: password,)).user;


        // User user = result.user;
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'invalid-email':
          {
            return 'Email is not valid';
          }
        case 'user-disabled':
          {
            return 'Account is not active';
          }
        case 'user-not-found':
          {
            return 'No user found';
          }
        case 'wrong-password':
          {
            return 'wrong password';
          }
        default:
          {
            return 'Unexpected error!';
          }
      }
    }
    return null;


  }
```

It looks different because I changed it like it was before that so I can check if maybe it was on the changes it do because it runs at this point.

Comment: https://youtu.be/TLGe44gaEUM

Comment: Yes that also the video I was watching and using but not working. It works like he doing it but as I sad when im reload the app user logged in hompega before verifying email.

Comment: so you need verify this every user logining right?

Comment: So you said, when user move himself to verifying screen, and try Loging it doesn't check email verification so user didn't verified, but auth working. if i understood right, tell me pls i could put an answer

Comment: No user dont go to verify screen. When im restarting the app. user logged in. But user in dont verify email.Im just schowing a message . Like check your email account. But not in the app so no button from my side

Comment: What I want is when user. restart the app he dont get automatically  inside hompegae without verifying his mail and also dont  can sig in without verifying his mail hope you understood.

Comment: Got it dude, i'll give answer soon\

Comment: ok im  excited!!!

Comment: the problem is the The getter 'emailVerified' was called on null.  But how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check email verification within you're sign-in method, and if the email was verified then return `instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

full code:

```dart
Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {

 try {
      if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.emailVerified) {
        ( await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email.trim(), password: password,)).user;
        return "success";
        // User user = result.user;
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'invalid-email':
          {
            return 'Email is not valid';
          }
        case 'user-disabled':
          {
            return 'Account is not active';
          }
        case 'user-not-found':
          {
            return 'No user found';
          }
        case 'wrong-password':
          {
            return 'wrong password';
          }
        default:
          {
            return 'Unexpected error!';
          }
      }
    }
    return return "error";;


  }
```

so every moment when `signIN` calling it would check email verification and if it verified it would work if it isn't it will return "error" or other problem variants, and you can listen to response so when it gives you an error you should return a snackBar, if it returns `"success"` then you would navigate.

**Solution of logout issue:**

```dart
onPressed: ()  {
 FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((){
   Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginScreen.route (route) => false);
});
```

Comment: There's one Problem . The user variable  declared after user Credential the await step so I can't use it ...

Comment: ok wait got it im using Firebase FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.emailVerified. BOOM thanks a lot.Do you know maybe the answer of the other question?

Comment: which one you said?

Comment: Look at my post before the last code snippet

Comment: And I found a problem . When user email verification send to his account. And user dont verified he cannot logged in like we want, but after he verfyed he also cannot logged in. And if he restarts the app again also cannot logged in.  Dammmnnn

Comment: you should check the value of `signIN` and by following this, if it returns true you have to navigate to home, if it's not true so if it is false you should show snackBar (pls verify you account bla bla bla)

Comment: i dont know really what's went wrong and what you mean with you check the value of sig in because It runs when im removing the if statement . And the long out method also dont work like it should maybe you can check my post I post the console output .thanks

Comment: ok i solved the logout problem but the sig in problem is there.